# How to prevent jquery hover effect from activating on and off hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'm using blast.js and my hover effect triggers when you move the mouse over the element and when you move it out of the element. I want it to behave like a normal hover effect. I know that the hover effect usually is set up like:

```
$('h1').hover(function(){
  //code here
}, function(){
  //code here
});
```

but I'm not sure what I would put in the second function when using blast.js, to prevent it from happening twice.

I have a fiddle, but I don't know how to make blast work on the fiddle.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oLLpfccy/)

```
$(function() {

  $('h1').hover(function() {
    // Blasts the title
    var chars = $('h1').blast({
      delimiter: 'word'
    });
    // Animation character per character
    chars.each(function(i) {
      // Initialization of the position
      $(this).css({
        position: 'relative',
        left: 0
      }).delay(i * 45).animate({
        left: '50px'
      }, 300).delay(200).animate({
        left: 0
      }, 300);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you only want it to occur on when you enter the element with the mouse? If so, you might want to use `.mouseenter` instead of `.hover`. In that context, you'd only need one callback function.

Comment: You need to add the fully qualified url for external scripts in JSfiddle.

Comment: thanks mouseenter works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.mouseover()` for when the cursor enters the object and `.mouseout()` for when the cursor leaves the object.

These are JQuery functions based on HTML events. There are also other events like `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, you can find them in [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You should add param to your function:

```
$('h1').hover(function(e) { ... });
```

and call inside of the body:

```
e.preventDefault();
```